# Generating PDF in Orbeon

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, orbeon

We would like to generate a PDF without using the existing "PDF" button, but we would like to add our own button that gets a custom template and generates a document filled by the data in the form.

Which Orbeon API we can use for this purpose? This API will get the form id and the PDF template and will generate the document.

The API should give us the possibility to :

- Map data to the PDF.
- Save the PDF in a given directory.
- Sdd some changes to the PDF like adding an image and save the document (this will be our custom code).
- Download the PDF after process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for sounds very much like Orbeon Forms' [PDF template](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/pdf-templates.html) feature. With Form Runner, you can add your own buttons to the form, and those buttons can have their own label and "logic". The latter is defined in a *process*, which is a sequence of *actions*. One of those actions is `send()`, which as its name implies, "sends" some information related to the form to a service you provide.

You can configure that action to send a PDF generated by "filling" a PDF template with the data entered by users in the form by using `send(content = "pdf"`). You can find more about this in the [documentation for the `send()` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#send).